# ANTLR problem with binding

Tags: java, antlr

I have strings like this:

```
`(val1, val2, val3)`
```

And I have ANTLR grammar to parse this code:

```
grammar TEST;

tokens {
 ORB = '(';
 CRB = ')';
 COMA = ',';
}

@members{

}
/*Parser rule*/
mainRule 
    :    ORB WORD (COMA WORD)* CRB;

/*Lexer rule*/

WORD    :    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+;

WS      :   ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

Now I need to map all `WORD`s into Java. How can I bind value when target token embraced into brackets?

Many thanks!

Comment: You mentioned that several people gave you helpful answers--how about voting up those questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same as JS Bangs' answer, only here's a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) you can compile and run and I showed how you can "label" your tokens and access them to put them in the List the mainRule is returning. Also note that the `init` needs an `@` sign in front of it (at least ANTLR v3 expects it).

```
grammar Test;

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String text = "(a, bb ,  ccc )";
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(text);
    TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    System.out.println(new TestParser(tokens).mainRule());
  }
}

mainRule returns [List<String> words]
@init{$words = new ArrayList<String>();}
  :  '(' w=WORD {$words.add($w.text);} (',' w=WORD {$words.add($w.text);} )* ')'
  ;

WORD
  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+
  ;

WS
  :  ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; }
  ;
```

And then:

```
bart@hades:~/Temp$ java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Test.g
bart@hades:~/Temp$ javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Temp$ java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar TestParser
[a, bb, ccc]
bart@hades:~/Temp$
```

On Windows the commands above are pretty much the same, only run your `TestParser` like this:

```
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar TestParser
```

(there's a semi-colon instead of a regular colon)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the textual value of a matched token with the `.text` property. Like this:

```
 string s = $WORD.text
```

Depending on what your overall grammar is supposed to do, it may be proper to add the `$WORD.text` string to an internal list, pass it to some other function, or to turn it into the return value from `mainRule`. For example, if you want `mainRule` to give you back the list of parsed strings, you can write the following:

```
mainRule returns [List strings] @init { $strings = new Vector(); }:
    ORB 
    WORD { $strings.add($WORD.text); } 
    ( COMMA WORD { $strings.add($WORD.text); } )*
    CRB
    ;
```

Comment: Not sure if you forgot the `@` before `init`, or if it's ANTLR v2 syntax. In ANTLR v3, you should put an `@` in front of it.

Comment: Thanks!
I don't know about @init keyword. Your answer is very helpful for me.


P.S. You have some errors in your example, this is correct code:
    mainRule2 returns [List strings] @init { $strings = new Vector(); }:
    ORB 
    val0=WORD { $strings.add($val0.text); } 
    ( COMA val1=WORD { $strings.add($val1.text); } )*
    CRB;

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, could you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do?
As I get it you want to bind each word to a java variable, correct?

```
words+=WORD (COMA words+=WORD)* {$words}
```

Here you define a label `words` (which is actually a list) and add every occurence of `WORD` to that label using the += syntax. You can then refer to this label as shown `$words`

Have a look at the ANTLR-Documentation and look for labels.
If you want to do something sophisticated with your parser I recommend Terrence Parr's book on ANTLR. It has a very good introducory chapter to the general topic of parsing and is the best reference for ANTLR.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! 
This is exactly what I mean! 
Sorry for poorly formulated question, english is not my native language

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helps you, don't forget to mark it.
I don't think SO-flair points are traded on ebay (yet) ;-)